# subgroup of finite index implies there is a short exact sequence

Tags: group-theory, exact-sequence

Given a complex $Y$ and a map $Y\to S^1$, I am told that the induced map $\pi_1(Y)\to \pi_1(S^1)$ having image of finite index implies that there is a short exact sequence $$1\to H \to\pi_1(Y)\to \pi_1(S^1)\to 1.$$

I'm not sure why this is true, especially since the map to $\pi_1(S^1)$ is not surjective.

Comment: Hint: What are finite index subgroups of ${\mathbb Z}$ isomorphic to?

Comment: @MoisheKohan $n\mathbb{Z}$ for some finite $n$, but isn't that an isomorphism and not an equality?

Comment: Nobody says that the homomorphism $\pi_1(Y)\to \pi_1(S^1)$ in your exact sequence comes from the original map $Y\to S^1$!